# Define Scaffolding.  (with respect to Dynamic Data and ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic-data, scaffolding, asp.net-dynamic-data, scaffold

There is a lot of information about how to implement and customize scaffolding with Dynamic Data and ASP.NET MVC.  What exactly is the definition of scaffolding when used in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the Dynamic Data framework will auto-generate a set of routes based on the table names in a data model (e.g. a Linq to SQL data context), and a predefined set of operations (essentially CRUD). When you e.g. visit `http://example.com/Products/Details.aspx`, where "Products" is the name of a table in your data model, the framework will auto-generate a details page for displaying product details. The generated pages can be customized by providing partial views named according to a convention based on the naming of e.g. columns in the data model.